# Asynchronous Ruby SNMP Library

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, snmp

Can anyone suggest a Ruby SNMP library with asynchronous requests support (just like SNMP4J, but for Ruby)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/normelton/snmp4em

From Readme: This library extends the [Ruby-SNMP](http://snmplib.rubyforge.org) to use the asynchronous [EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com) library for added performance and scalability.